# Mysterious jPlayer 2.0.0 error on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jplayer

My client has a page listing his music here: http://bit.ly/flbgwm. Each song has its own player powered by jPlayer 2.0.0. They're working in Safari/Chrome, but not in Firefox, which uses Flash to play mp3's. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Here's an example of the code for one of the songs:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1">mute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1">unmute</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="jp-progress">
            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
      <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                  <a class="DownloadLink" href="[My download file]">download mp3</a>
      </div>
</div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: "[The mp3 link]"
                });
            },
            play: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            },
            supplied: 'mp3',
            swfPath: 'custom/',
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_interface_1"
        });
  });
</script>
```

Both the jPlayer javascript file and the jPlayer swf file are up to date, as are the paths above. Does anyone have any idea why this code wouldn't work in Firefox? I can't find any conflicts with any other script. (I'm using jQuery 1.5.1.)

Comment: Hey, I have this exact problem; have you figured it out? One thing to check is that your crossdomain.xml file is setup (not my problem unfortunately). I've also tapped into the error events and I get "jplayer_error" but no other info. Setup the jquery.jplayer.inspector.js as well if you haven't. The only oddity I'm seeing is that the media.status is empty and it should have my mp3 file path... not sure if this is a cause or effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks for the music relative to the SWF file in this case, not the html, because Firefox uses the flash version.  It's possible it's not finding your music if you're using relative paths instead of an http link to the songs.